# Remove an Item From an Array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had an array with two objects (can be much more). Like the following

```
var array = [{ 'a':'hello', 'b': 'world' }, { 'a':'new', 'b': 'world' }];
```

And I had an object with extra values to delete from that array. Ex

```
var objectInarray = { 'a':'hello', 'b': 'world', 'c': 'extra' }
```

How I can delete ?

**Edited:**

I want to delete array's value `{ 'a':'hello', 'b': 'world' }` using `objectInarray` . Final result will be like the following

```
 var array = [{ 'a':'new', 'b': 'world' }];
```

When we had removed unwanted array's value.

Comment: Please also give what is the expected output.

Comment: @sb it's difference.

Comment: Sometimes what you think is obvious, may not be. It will be better if you specify the ouptput explicitly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your requirement correctly. If there's any change required, do let me know in the comments.

```
var array = [{ 'a':'hello', 'b': 'world' }, { 'a':'new', 'b': 'world' }];
var objectInarray = { 'a':'hello', 'b': 'world', 'c': 'extra' };

var opArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    var element = array[i];
    var isAllPresent = true;
    for(key in element){
        if(!(objectInarray[key] && objectInarray[key] === element[key] )){
            isAllPresent = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!isAllPresent){
        opArray.push(element);
    }
}

console.log(opArray);
```

`opArray` will have remaining items.